# Fsharp : Array contain Tuples

Tags: f#

```
open System

type Point(X:int,Y:int) =
  member this.x = X
  member this.y = Y

let fib  = 
    seq {
        for i in 1..10 do 
            yield Point(1,2) 
        }

fib |> printf("%A")

Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

And result when I run code :

```
seq [File1+Point; File1+Point; File1+Point; File1+Point; ...]
```

Why it's string not numbers ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when `printf()` receives the item and attempts to output it, it converts it to a string by calling `ToString()` on each object.

To fix this, you need to define your own `ToString()` method which gives the intended output.

Here's an example of one way you could fix this;

```
type Point(X:int,Y:int) =
  member this.x = X
  member this.y = Y

  override this.ToString() =
        String.Format("({0},{1})", this.x, this.y)
```

Using this definition for `Point(x,y)`, it gives you each point as `(1,2)` in the output.

The general advice here applies to all .net languages, as they all use that same `ToString()` method to produce a printable output for the object.

Answer (score 0):

Another , we can use :

```
type Point(x:float,y:float) =
    member this.x = x
    member this.y = y
    member this.scale(k) = Point(k * x, k * y)

let s = 
    seq{
        for i in (1.1)..(2.2)..(9.9) do 
            yield Point(i,i)
        }

s |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn("%f %f\n") x.x x.y)
```